# How to evict or "kill" open connections when these are above a fixed limit (using dbcp w/ oracle)

Tags: java, oracle, apache-commons, apache-commons-dbcp

Does anyone know how to evict or kill open connections (in use or not it doesn't matter) if the number of connections is above of a fixed limit (e.g. maxActive) Currently I'm using DBCP from Apache under a Sun One 6.1.
Thanks in advance!,

Comment: Better to figure out how to close them when you're done with them.  If you've gotten to the point where you have to worry about connections above a limit it's likely that your code is wrong.

Comment: yes, I know we have a bug but it's just a workaround while we look for the error. I just want to know if there is any way to do that.

Comment: if you kill open connections especially when they are in use, you might be creating new bugs. Given the manner in which JDBC drivers are written, killing the physical connection will make the logical connection object's state inconsistent and will only result in "weirder" behavior.

Answer (score 0):

ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION 'nnn,mmmm' can kill sessions (with nnn being the SID and mmmm the SERIAL#). You can look at v$session seconds_in_wait and with an event of 'SQL*Net message from client' for sessions that haven't been doing anything in a while. That event basically says "I'm waiting for a client to tell me what to do next."

Also make sure the session doesn't have an open transaction

```
select sid, serial# from v$session 
where event = 'SQL*Net message from client'
and saddr not in (select ses_addr from v$transaction)
order by seconds_in_wait desc;
```

It's an ugly solution though.